# JQuery UI Autocomplete not getting data from generated JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Hello I know that here are many issues about JQuery UI Autocomplete but none of them, as far as I know, really fits my needs.
I'm doing this from a json file, which is constructed encoding this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [label] => 76
            [value] => Museo de la Iglesia
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [label] => 86
            [value] => Iglesia de los Padres
        )  

...
```

Printing it like this at the end of the php file:

```
echo json_encode($rows);
```

My script is really simple as well, almost copied from the official page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
     $( "#field" ).autocomplete({
       minLength: 1,
       appendTo: "#result",
       source: "search.php"
    });
  });
</script>
```

And my form

```
<div class="container col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
  <h1> Test de autocompletado</h1>
  <form>
    <div class="form-group ui-widget">
      <label for="autocomplete">Campo de autocompletado</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Introduce texto" id="field">
    </div>
  </form>
  <div id="result"></div>
</div>
```

I don't get it, the JSON I think is OK, the form triggers the script and the php queries the db. I'm not even passing any parameter, just doing the same query all the time to get the same results.

What am I missing?

EDIT: After some research I've found with the help of @guest271314 that the error is in the JSON this is what I've made so far:

```
var_dump(json_encode($rows)); //bool(false)
echo json_last_error(); // 5 = JSON_ERROR_UTF8
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the problem you have? Have you checked the console for any errors?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The thing is, I'm not getting any feedback, that's why I am this lost

Comment: Ok, but what is/is not happening?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  
I'm just getting what I imagine is a default library message which says No search results and a white browser console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot append menu to `input` element `#field`. Change `appendTo` to element where results should be shown

See [`appendTo`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-appendTo)

> Which element the menu should be appended to. When the value is `null`,
>   the parents of the input field will be checked for a class of
>   `ui-front`. If an element with the `ui-front` class is found, the menu
>   will be appended to that element. Regardless of the value, if no
>   element is found, the menu will be appended to the body.

Comment: Yep sorry you are right but that's not the issue, I don't get data yet : /

Comment: @Asur Can you describe _"I don't get data yet"_ ?

Comment: Yes sorry that wasn't a proper answer but I'm trying your solution, basically I have the same as you made in that fiddle, but I still dont get the autocomplete field so I guess that the problem is with my php right? the thing is that the sample JSON was got just before the script encoded the array and prints it, so I don't understant why it is not properly returning the JSON.